# Having difficulties with node.js res.send() loop

Tags: node.js, express

I'm attempting to write a very basic scraper that loops through a few pages and outputs all the data from each url to a single json file. The url structure goes as follows:

http://url/1
http://url/2
http://url/n

Each of the urls has a table, which contains information pertaining to the ID of the url. This is the data I am attempting to retrieve and store inside a json file.

I am still extremely new to this and having a difficult time moving forward. So far, my code looks as follows:

```
app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){
    var json;
    for (var i = 1163; i < 1166; i++){
        url = 'https://urlgoeshere.com' + i;
        request(url, function(error, response, html){
            if(!error){
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            var mN, mL, iD;
            var json = { mN : "", mL : "", iD: ""};

            $('html body div#wrap h2').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this);
                mN = data.text();        
                json.mN = mN;
            })
            $('table.vertical-table:nth-child(7)').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this);
                mL = data.text();        
                json.mL = mL;
            })
            $('table.vertical-table:nth-child(8)').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this);
                iD = data.text();        
                json.iD = iD;
            })
        }

        fs.writeFile('output' + i + '.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err){

            console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output' + i + '.json file');

        })

    });
}

res.send(json);
})

app.listen('8081')
console.log('Magic happens on port 8081');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

When I run the code as displayed above, the output within the output.json file only contains data for the last url. I presume that's because I attempt to save all the data within the same variable?

If I include res.send() inside the loop, so the data writes after each page, I receive the error that multiple headers cannot be sent.

Can someone provide some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Ideal output I would like to see:
    Page ID: 1
    Page Name: First Page
    Color: Blue

```
Page ID: 2
Page Name: Second Page
Color: Red

Page ID: n
Page Name: Nth Page
Color: Green
```

Comment: Besides the problems with your asynchronous operations inside a loop (the loop doesn't wait for the `request()` to finish), it's not even clear what you're tring to accomplish.  Inside the loop, you're just overwriting the same properties `json.mN`, `json.mL` and `json.iD` over and over again.  Then, in the end, you try to send `res.send(json)`.  What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Yeah I'm really new at this, and realize my code is terrible. Sorry about that. 
My goal is to navigate to each page (the ID of the page keeps increasing, hence the for loop), write some data to a variable, and output the data from each page into the same json file.

Comment: Also, not clear what you're trying to do with the three `.filter()` methods?  I can help you, but you need to answer the questions I've asked.

Comment: Maybe you need to back up and describe (in words) what you want this code to do.  Please add this description to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a number of problems:

1. Your `loop` doesn't wait for the asynchronous operations in the loop, thus you do some things like `res.send()` before the asynchronous operations in the loop have completed.
2. In appropriate use of cheerio's `.filter()`.
3. Your `json` variable is constantly being overwritten so it only has the last data in it.
4. Your loop variable `i` would lose its value by the time you tried to use it in the `fs.writeFile()` statement.

Here's one way to deal with those issues:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

app.get('/scrape', async function(req, res) {
    let data = [];
    for (let i = 1163; i < 1166; i++) {
        const url = 'https://urlgoeshere.com/' + i;
        try {
            const html = await rp(url)
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);

            const mN = $('html body div#wrap h2').first().text();
            const mL = $('table.vertical-table:nth-child(7)').first().text();
            const iD = $('table.vertical-table:nth-child(8)').first().text();

            // create object for this iteration of the loop
            const obj = {iD, mN, mL};

            // add this object to our overall array of all the data
            data.push(obj);

            // write a file specifically for this invocation of the loop
            await fsp.writeFile('output' + i + '.json', JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
            console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output' + i + '.json file');
        } catch(e) {
            // stop further processing on an error
            console.log("Error scraping ", url, e);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
    }
    // send all the data we accumulated (in an array) as the final result
    res.send(data);
});
```

Things different in this code:

1. Switch over all variable declarations to `let` or `const`
2. Declare route handler as `async` so we can use `await` inside.
3. Use the request-promise module instead of request.  It has the same features, but returns a promise instead of using a plain callback.
4. Use the promise-based `fs` module (in latest versions of node.js).
5. Use `await` in order to serialize our two asynchronous (now promise-returning) operations so the `for` loop will pause for them and we can have proper sequencing.
6. Catch errors and stop further processing and return an error status.
7. Accumulate an object of data for each iteration of the `for` loop into an array.
8. Change `.filter()` to `.first()`.
9. Make the response to the request handler be a JSON array of data.

FYI, you can tweak the organization of the data in `obj` however you want, but the point here is that you end up with an array of objects, one for each iteration of the `for` loop.

---

**EDIT Jan, 2020 - request() module in maintenance mode**

FYI, the `request` module and its derivatives like [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) are now in maintenance mode and will not be actively developed to add new features.  You can read more about the reasoning [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode).  There is a list of alternatives in [this table](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode#alternativestorequest) with some discussion of each one.  I have been using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself and it's built from the beginning to use promises and is simple to use.